Remote Redis connectivity with auth key + server-ca.pem file
I am working on Spring boot project which connect with Redis. With local setup everything worked fine.
But now application will connect to remote server Redis with read and write separate endpoints as :

Read Enpoint
12.11.13.4
6378

Write Endpoint
12.11.13.5
6378


I have given other two info with Redis remote IP

server-ca.pem

auth keys


my application.yml have this redis info


spring:
  cache:
    type: redis
  redis:
    write:
      host: read_ip
      port: 6378
      password: redis_auth_key
      ssl: true
      sslOptions:
        trustStore: classpath:server_ca.pem 
        trustStorePassword: 
    read:
      host: write_ip
      port: 6378
      password: redis_auth_key
      ssl: true
      sslOptions:
        trustStore: classpath:server_ca.pem  
        trustStorePassword:



I have to connect Redis using Lettuce, so I have tried many way to connect Lettuce in secure way for that :

Added new version of lettuce-core in code, but now downloading dependencies, getting error : Could not find artifact io.lettuce.core:lettuce-ssl:jar:6.4.0.RELEASE in central (
https://repo.maven.apache.org/maven2)



 <dependency>
                <groupId>io.lettuce.core</groupId>
                <artifactId>lettuce-core</artifactId>
                <version>6.4.0.RELEASE</version>
            </dependency>



even tried many versions of Lettuce, not worked.

I have update spring boot redis maven dependecies to get lates version of lettuce, but not worked



        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.springframework.data</groupId>
            <artifactId>spring-data-redis</artifactId>
            <version>3.3.4</version>
        </dependency>




Excluded the dependency of Lettuce from Redis, not worked.

Code for RedisConfig


import com.google.api.client.util.Value;
import io.lettuce.core.SslOptions;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.RedisStandaloneConfiguration;
import org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory;

import java.io.File;

@Configuration
public class RedisConfig {

    @Value("${spring.redis.write.host}")
    private String writeHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.write.port}")
    private int writePort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.write.password}")
    private String writePassword;

    @Value("${spring.redis.read.host}")
    private String readHost;

    @Value("${spring.redis.read.port}")
    private int readPort;

    @Value("${spring.redis.read.password}")
    private String readPassword;

    @Value("${spring.redis.read.sslOptions.trustStore}")
    private String readTrustStore;

    @Bean
    public LettuceConnectionFactory connectionFactory() {
        RedisStandaloneConfiguration redisConf = new RedisStandaloneConfiguration();
        redisConf.setHostName(readHost);
        redisConf.setPort(readPort);
        redisConf.setPassword(readPassword);
        LettuceConnectionFactory factory = new LettuceConnectionFactory(redisConf);
        factory.setUseSsl(true);
        factory.setSslOptions(SslOptions.builder().trustManager(new File("path/to/server-ca.pem")).build());
        return factory;
    }
}



In above code it showing error of   factory.setSslOptions(SslOptions.builder().trustManager(new File("path/to/server-ca.pem")).build());
Lettuce not getting setSslOptions method and also not ssl related things I am finding. How can I set server-ca.pem file to use to connect securely.
Are the configuration need to changes in yml?
Is there any way I can connect Redis securely using server-ca.pem file and auth key with read and write endpoints separately?
